# Mysterious error; private variable of C++ class not printing its value even after initialization

Tags: c++

I have made a class String which has two private members int length and a character pointer.
There are two constructors which initialize these members.
My question why s1.print() is not working in my code?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class String {
  int length;
  char * ptr;
  public:
    String(int N, char s[]) {
      ptr = new char[N];
      strcpy(s, ptr);
    }
  String(int N) {
    ptr = new char[N];
  }
  String concat(String s2) {
    String result(s2.length + length, strcat(ptr, s2.ptr));
  }
  void print(void) {
    cout << ptr << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  char temp[50];
  cin >> temp;
  String s1(strlen(temp) + 1, temp);
  //String s2(strlen(temp)+1, temp);
  s1.print();
  //s1.concat(s2);
  //s1.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: strcpy(destination, source)

Comment: `String result(s2.length+length, strcat(ptr, s2.ptr));` will bite you too. You don't have enough memory allocated to `ptr` for the `strcat` (and I'm not sure you 0-terminate your contents always).

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the char* you need to cast it to string and than print.
Another thing I suggest that your array size will be N + 1 and add a NULL-terminate at ptr[N] = '\0'

Comment: Hello, now that I am revisiting this old question due to question limit imposed by stack overflow community, I appreciate your answer which is a good tip for the code. But, answer to the question is correctly given by src in the comments. Thank you for your time.